# TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable , how can i solve it please?

Tags: python

Please here is my code

```py
mask = np.reshape(binarized_predict_masks[j], newshape=(input_img_size, input_img_size))
       
resized_mask = Image.fromarray(mask).resize((size, size))
              
cropped_resized_mask = resized_mask[((size-w)//2):((size-w)//2 + w), ((size-h)//2):((size-h)//2 + h)]
```

According to the python terminal here is the line of code that returns an error to me:

```
TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable
```

```py
cropped_resized_mask = resized_mask[((size-w)//2):((size-w)//2 + w), ((size-h)//2):((size-h)//2 + h)]
```

Please help me how can i solve this TypeError? Thank you so much for all answers.

Comment: `resized_mask` is an `Image` object. The error says _"'Image' object is not subscriptable"_ which is telling you that it does not support the syntax with square brackets i.e. you can't do this `resized_mask[...]`

Comment: probably you need to do your array cropping operations on a copy of `mask` np array and then instantiate a new Image from that

Comment: thank you very much for your answer explained. Please can you try translating this into a line of code so I understand more? I am a beginner in python

Answer (score 0):

mask is an Image, not an array. Crop the NumPy array then convert it to an image.